# How to send a Polars `Expr`/`PyExpr`/`LogicalPlan` from Python to Rust?

Tags: python, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

In a single process, I could write an Polars `Expr` and then use it on `DataFrame` by `with_column` or `select`.

But in another scenario of realtime financial data, I have a rust process which has a lot of history and realtime data(`DataFrame`) as a server. There are multiple python process(client) need to put their own `Expr`/`PyExpr`/`LogicalPlan` on the same data.

Because the data is changing time by time, so I need to avoid frequently data copy from rust to python. Is there a way to send the `Expr`/`PyExpr`/`LogicalPlan` from python client to rust server, then calculate the result in rust with its data so the copy job would be much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because the data is changing time by time, so I need to avoid frequently data copy from rust to python

You can move `DataFrames` and `Series` between `python` and `rust` for free within the same process. We just swap arrow pointers.

You can use the `pyo3-polars` crate to make this easy.

https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars

Comment: Thank you. If the data source api is an independent rust process, could it swap coming arrow pointers to some other python processes and then wrapped as PyDataFrame?

Comment: No, the process must be the same for pointer reads. Otherwise you must serialize the data and deserialize on the other side.